# Global Variable From Inner Function - Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, global-variables

I am trying to write an Angular code that will read constants from other URL and put those constants into current constant module.

Here is my sample Javascript:

```
var application = angular.module('mainApp', [])
.run(['$http', function($http){

alert('h1');

var gc;

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.response);
        window.gc = this.response;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "myconst.properties", true);
  xhttp.send();

  alert(window.gc);


}]).controller('myController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
$scope.greetMessage = $rootScope.data;
});
```

Whatever I am using instead `run` like `provider` or `config` , `alert(window.gc)` always returning the undefined even if I'm using `$http` instead `XMLHttpRequest`, it remains the same. I am not using Angular constant because there is a huge number of constants are in there. I am avoiding that list of constants in my current script page.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: used `$rootScope` directive in xmlHttpRequest

Comment: the HTTP module is asynchronous which mean your code still runs while the network request happens, `window.gc` only exists after the call to onreadystatechanage has been made.

Answer (score 0):

> used $rootScope directive here

```js
var application = angular.module('mainApp', [])
.run(['$http','$rootScope', function($http,$rootScope){

alert('h1');

var gc;
$rootScope.gc = {};

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.response);
        window.gc = this.response;
        $rootScope.gc = this.response;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "myconst.properties", true);
  xhttp.send();

  alert($rootScope.gc);

}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="mainApp">

</div>
```

Comment: Its remains the same. $rootScope.gc object is empty

Comment: i think your response is empty

Comment: No. Its not. The response has some data.